# Checking message and then re-queueing it if needed in rabbitmq consumer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I am looking for a way for the consumer to take the received message from the queue, invoke a method on it, then check if the task is done & if not to re-queue it.
the check is simple, I check an int property inside the message 
I am having trouble with it because it fires an event and you can't consume inside the event so you can't do the check on it inside...
Any ideas?

code:

```
 EventingBasicConsumer consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);


                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageWithoutUser>(msg);

                    IBot bot = _factory.GetBot(message);
                    var result = bot.Execute(message.MessageId, message.UserId, message.Likes, message.Service, message.Time);

                    if (CheckResult(result))
                    {
                        _channel.BasicConsume(queue: "messages",

                                    autoAck: true,
                                    consumer: consumer);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var newJsonMessage = new MessageWithoutUser { MessageId = message.MessageId, UserId = message.UserId, Likes = result, Service = message.Service, Time = message.Time };
                        var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newJsonMessage);
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newJson);
                        ea.Body = SerializeMessage(newJsonMessage);
                        _channel.BasicReject(ea.DeliveryTag,true);
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();
                };
```

as you can see there is a .BasicConsume inside the Received event, which is impossible and that is what I'm looking to do, take the result, then check if its 1 or 0, then based on that consume or reject.

Answer (score 0):

- You can acknowledge message by `_channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, true)`
- Reject message means requeue the **same** message, there is no way to change already published message content.
- If you want to change the requeue message content, reject it with `_channel.BasicReject(ea.DeliveryTag, false)`, rabbitmq server will discard this message, and then republish the message with your custom content.